# How to find the unit normal vector for typical solid region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, spheres

For instance, normal for sphere is easily written as

$$\frac{\langle x,y,z\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},$$

because the position vector $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is always perpendicular to tangent plane, and we use $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ to make it unit.

But how about other typical solid regions like paraboloid, rectangular box, cylinder, etc.. Is there a general formula?

Comment: Just use differentiation

Comment: Before you ask for a single general formula for the *normal* of various regions, can you say whether you know a single general formula for the regions themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Describe the surface of your region in the form $f(x,y,z)=0$
Then the unit normal vector is given by

$$\hat n= \frac{\vec \nabla f}{ |\vec \nabla f|  } = \frac{  \left<  \frac { \partial f}{\partial x}, \frac { \partial f}{\partial y}, \frac { \partial f}{\partial z} \right >}{
\sqrt{  ( \frac { \partial f}{\partial x} )^2+(  \frac { \partial f}{\partial y} )^2   +( \frac { \partial f}{\partial z})^2  }
}$$